# Can't match alphanumeric with regex in antlr4

Tags: regex, antlr4

I'm trying to match alhphanumeric symbols for a pseudo code language for example:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int k = i+j;
if (k > 2)
  k = k + 1;
fi;
loop (i < 10)
  i = i + 1;
  j = j + 1;
  k = i + j;
  print(k);
pool;
```

where `i,j,k` are variable symbols, `int` is a type symbol and `if,loop` are scope symbols. I tried to match them with `ID` token `ID : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;` and it works, however, when I changed it to `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+;` it will not match any of these tokens except `loop`. I know `*` means match 0 or many, `+` means match 1 or many. To my understanding, they both should match these tokens anyway, why only `*` works?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+` doesn't match `i` because `i` is only one character, but your regex requires at least two.

Comment: I see what you mean,thanks.